# Error on "instanceOf" when checking a subClass

Tags: java, extends, instanceof

I have a method, that accepts as parameter all classes that extend `Persona.Class` (`Uomo.Class` and `Donna.Class` extend `Persona.Class`).

```
public PersonaDecorator(Class <? extends Persona> persona) {            
    }
```

Inside this method, I need to know if the class sent to the method is `Uomo.Class` or `Donna.Class`.

I Thought I could do something like this:

```
public PersonaDecorator(Class <? extends Persona> persona) {    
    if(persona instanceof Uomo){
        ......
    }       
}
```

But I get this error: `Incompatible conditional operand types Class<capture#1-of ? extends Persona> and Uomo`

Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't be `PersonaDecorator(Persona persona)` also an option?

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right. Then I have a question: when choose PersonaDecorator(Persona persona) over PersonaDecorator(Class <? extends Persona> persona) and viceversa?

Comment: If this is on any scale it is a job for the Visitor pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `instanceof` operator tests whether a reference (the left operand) refers to an object which is an instance of the class named on the right operand.

Here, `persona` will be a reference to an instance of `Class`, and an instance of `Class` can never be an instance of `Persona`. You're testing for an impossible condition, and the compiler is helpfully telling you about that mistake.

I suspect you want `Class.isAssignableFrom`:

```
if (Uomo.class.isAssignableFrom(persona))
```

That would find subclasses of `Uomo` as well. If you want to test whether it's *exactly* the `Uomo` class, you can just use:

```
if (persona == Uomo.class)
```

Comment: Thank you, isAssignableFrom is what I needed :)

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali There might be a risk. In case `persona` would be a subclass of `Uomo` then `Uomo.class.isAssignableFrom(persona)` would be true as well.

Comment: Persona can't be a subclass of Uomo. Only Uomo can be a subclass of Persona

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali: In that case there's a simpler option - see my edit. I thought you wanted a subclass-compatible check in the same way that `instanceof` is.